# Limitar acertos do anagrama - Java

Tags: java

Eu tenho um código que verifica se o usuário digitou uma palavra existente no anagrama, mas se ele digita a mesma palavra 10 vezes ele conta como 10 acertos, eu gostaria de limitar isso a 1 vez somente.
O código que tenho feito é este:

```
String palavra[] = {"BAR", "OLA", "ALO"}; // Maneira mais elegante de inicializar um vetor

String p = jTextField1.getText(); 

// Recupera String do componente textfield.

boolean existe = false; // Declaro uma flag que indica se encontrou ou não uma palavra igual.

for (int i = 0 ; i < 3; i++) {

    if (palavra[i].equals(p)) { // Percorre vetor de acordo com i.

        existe = true; // Altera valor da flag.

       break; // Sai do laço se encontrou palavra igual.
   }

}


if (existe==true) {

//verifica flag

    cont++;

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Acertos :"+cont+"de 3");



} else if (existe==false){

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "NAO EXISTE");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não postou o código todo, mas vamos supor que esteja mais ou menos assim:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Anagramas extends JFrame {

    private JTextField jTextField1;
    private int cont;

    public Anagrama() {
        // ...
    }

    public void achaAnagrama() {
        String palavra[] = {"BAR", "OLA", "ALO"}; // Maneira mais elegante de inicializar um vetor

        String p = jTextField1.getText(); 

        // Recupera String do componente textfield.

        boolean existe = false; // Declaro uma flag que indica se encontrou ou não uma palavra igual.

        for (int i = 0 ; i < 3; i++) {

            if (palavra[i].equals(p)) { // Percorre vetor de acordo com i.

                existe = true; // Altera valor da flag.

               break; // Sai do laço se encontrou palavra igual.
           }

        }


        if (existe==true) {

        //verifica flag

            cont++;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Acertos :"+cont+"de 3");



        } else if (existe==false){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "NAO EXISTE");
        }
    }

}
```

Primeira coisa que noto, é que é melhor mudar o nome do *array* `palavra` para `palavras` no plural, afinal de contas o *array* contém várias palavras, e não uma palavra só.

Aliás, qual é melhor? Usar `String[] palavras` ou `String palavras[]`? Com `String[] palavras` nós temos a notação usual, tipo da variável (`String[]`) seguido do nome. Já com `String palavras[]`, nós temos o tipo definido pela metade (`String`), seguido do nome da variável, seguido de alguma coisa que vai modificar o tipo outrora declarado, algo que é desnecessariamente mais complicado. Além disso, quem passar os olhos rapidamente no código, pode não perceber o `[]` depois do nome da variável e imaginar que o tipo é simplesmente `String` ao invés de `String[]`. Por esse motivo, é melhor declarar assim:

```
String[] palavras = {"BAR", "OLA", "ALO"};
```

Também dá para dar uma simplificada nisso:

```
if (existe == true) {
    // ...
} else if (existe == false) {
    // ...
}
```

Comparar com `== true` é desnecessário. Usar simplesmente `if (existe) {` fica mais claro e mais simples. Além disso, se ele não entrar no `if`, então a única possibilidade é de que `existe` seja falso, e por isso o teste no `else if` é irrelavante, pois ele sempre resultará verdadeiro quando o fluxo atingir aquele ponto. Portanto o seu código poderia ser simplificado para isso:

```
if (existe) {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Uma outra coisa que há no seu código é isso:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 3; i++) {
// ...
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Acertos :"+cont+"de 3");
```

Por que 3? Porque 3 é o tamanho do seu *array*. Sendo assim, é melhor computar o tamanho do *array* ao invés de usar o 3 fixo, pois nesse caso, se você decidir colocar mais elementos no *array*, você não vai necessitar ter que arrumar o tamanho manualmente:

```
for (int i = 0; i < palavras.length; i++) {
// ...
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Acertos: " + cont + " de " + palavras.length);
```

E note também que tem espaço tanto antes quanto depois do "de" na mensagem.

Aliás, podemos até usar a sintaxe do *for-each* ao invés disso e nos livrarmos da complexidade de ter que controlar os índices na iteração, simplificando ainda mais o código:

```
for (String pa : palavra) {
    if (pa.equals(p)) {
        existe = true; // Altera valor da flag.
        break; // Sai do laço se encontrou palavra igual.
   }
}
```

O que você vai precisar saber não é contar quantas vezes ele acertou, mas quais foram os acertos. Afinal de contas, se ele já acertou antes e apenas repetiu a palavra, você tem que em algum lugar saber quais foram as palavras que já foram tentadas. Uma forma de fazer isso é guardar as palavras acertadas em um `Set`. E neste caso, você não vai mais precisar da variável `cont`, é só usar o tamanho do `Set`. Desta forma, o seu código fica assim:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Anagramas extends JFrame {

    private JTextField jTextField1;
    private Set<String> acertadas;

    public Anagrama() {
        // ...
        acertadas = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public void achaAnagrama() {
        String[] palavras = {"BAR", "OLA", "ALO"}; // Maneira mais elegante de inicializar um vetor

        String p = jTextField1.getText(); 

        // Recupera String do componente textfield.

        boolean existe = false; // Declaro uma flag que indica se encontrou ou não uma palavra igual.

        for (String pa : palavra) {
            if (pa.equals(p)) {
                existe = true; // Altera valor da flag.
                break; // Sai do laço se encontrou palavra igual.
            }
        }

        if (existe) {
            acertadas.add(p);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Acertos: " + acertadas.size() + " de " + palavras.length);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "NÃO EXISTE");
        }
    }
}
```

Dá para fazer ainda melhor? Dá sim. Se `palavras` também for um `Set`, ao invés de um *array*, você pode usar o método `contains` e eliminar o laço e também a variável `existe`, deixando o código bem simples:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Anagramas extends JFrame {

    private JTextField jTextField1;
    private Set<String> acertadas;
    private Set<String> palavras;

    public Anagrama() {
        // ...
        acertadas = new HashSet<>();
        palavras = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("BAR", "OLA", "ALO"));
    }

    public void achaAnagrama() {
        String p = jTextField1.getText(); // Recupera String do componente textfield.

        if (palavras.contains(p)) {
            acertadas.add(p);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Acertos: " + acertadas.size() + " de " + palavras.size());
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "NÃO EXISTE");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Essa resposta é muito boa, deveria ter mais votos :/

Comment: Cara , esta dando certo , parcialmente , não entendi esta parte :

 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Acertos: " + acertos.size() + " de " + palavra.length);

acertos.size ? 

Não esta saindo do 1 este valor conforme vou acertando as palavras , e preciso mostrar quantas foram acertadas para poder passar de fase apos acertar o minimo de 3 .

Desde ja agradeço !

Comment: @MateusRocha Opa, desculpe, é que mudei o nome da variável na última hora antes de postar e ficou isso para trás. Veja se agora está ok. Se depois disso ele não estiver saindo do 1, diga quais são as palavras que você está testando para eu fazer o mesmo teste também.